# jscript header reload same page

Tags: php, header, jscript

In my PHP site, I am using script alert for checking invalid username and password. If username and password are wrong, it shows a message box. When I click `ok` to it, user will be redirected to index.php page. But I want reload same page, like `header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);`.

This is my code :

```
echo "<script>alert('Invalid Username and Password'); 
location.href='index.php';
</script>";
```

Comment: What happens if you do alert and then `header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);` ?

Comment: am using jscript Sulthan

Comment: But i would recommend not to use `alert` instead you can just show the alert message as a dialogue **Default Alert Style is really too old ;)**

Comment: Just updating.. **JScript** belongs to Microsoft and **JavaScript** belongs to **Netscape** and opensource.

Comment: Sulthan really you are great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `location.reload()`

```
echo "<script>alert('Invalid Username and Password'); location.reload();</script>";
```

the `reload()` function also has an optional parameter:

- false - Default. Reloads the current page from the cache.
- true - Reloads the current page from the server

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Eval](https://eval.in/375519)

```
echo "<script>alert('Invalid Username and Password'); window.location.href='index.php';</script>";
```